# bash - counting the amount of specific char in a line

Tags: bash, grep

Would like to know how to count a specific char in a line. 
For an example :

```
Hey . My . Name . Is . Bash
```

With the char "." should return : 4

We were told grep would be usefull, but couldnt find a good way to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$ echo "Hey . My . Name . Is . Bash" | tr -cd . | wc -m`

I believe using `tr` is cheaper here.

Comment: how can I use this implementation on a string named word (i wanna count how many times a char appears in there without ruining the original string)

Comment: Just another small question, If I wanna save the output in a parameter, "amount" for example, how would I change the code ?

Comment: `amount=\`echo "Hey . My . Name . Is . Bash" | tr -cd . | wc -m\``

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways.

Like this for example:

```
$ echo "Hey . My . Name . Is . Bash" | grep -o "\." | wc -w
4
```

or with double grep:

```
$ echo "Hey . My . Name . Is . Bash" | grep -o "\."  | grep -c "\."
4
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$ echo "Hey . My . Name . Is . Bash" | grep -o '\.' | wc -l
4
```

Pure bash:

```
$ s="Hey . My . Name . Is . Bash"
$ m=${s//[^.]/}
$ echo ${#m}
4
```

yet another:

```
$ tr -C -d [\.] <<< $s | wc -c
4
```

Answer (score 1):

In pure bash:

```
str="Hey . My . Name . Is . Bash"
len=${#str}
str=${str//./}
len2=${#str}

count=$((len-len2))

echo "There are $count '.' in '$str'"
```

How it works:

- `${#var_name}` expands to the length of the value of variable var_name
- `${var_name//./}` replaces all occurences of `.` by the empty string

Try here: http://ideone.com/SLkLkL

Comment: Thanks for posting that link, this is a heck of a website. helped me alot

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do it with two processes.

If you want to count special (single) char in a line:

```
kent$  echo "Hey . My . Name . Is . Bash"|awk '{print split($0,a,".")-1}'
4
```

or:

```
kent$  echo "Hey . My . Name . Is . Bash"|awk '{print gsub("\\.","")}'
4
```